# Fancybox 1 or 2 overlay not showing with modal popup

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, overlay, fancybox-2

I tried both fancybox1 and fancybox2 and the overlay wouldn't show on a website I'm working on.

You can find the example [here](http://www.fineenergy.co.uk). In the first column where it says "Is my site suitable" enter in the textbox some uk postcode like "w1 3rt".

A pop up will appear but without the overlay.
I've been debugging this for a while and I can't find why the overlay isn't showing.

With fancybox 1 I got the overlay showing if I had "top: 1px" on the overlay instead of "top: 0px". I don't quite understand what's wrong with it...

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fancybox_overlay.png` file (fancybox 2) should be located on the same directory as the [modal css](http://www.fineenergy.co.uk/css/modal.css) file, otherwise this declaration (line 180)

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    background: url("fancybox_overlay.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    ....etc
}
```

... will fail.

Alternatively, you could edit the css file and set the **absolute** path of the `png` file instead.

Comment: Talk about an embarrassing oversight. I guess I was thrown off because in chrome it didn't appear as though the resource was missing

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same symptoms, overlay not showing, but the issue was not an image not found, but simply that I was invoking fancybox BEFORE the page's onload event. So make sure to invoke fancybox on page load and not before :)